# Pyinstaller and Django any collect_submodules failed to import

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pyinstaller

This problem is new to me.

When using extra libraries, they cannot be incorporated into the pyinstaller build.

As an example I tried using --hidden-import, --collect-submodules and added a hook-djoser.urls.py file to try to solve one of the other problems. In this file I did this.

hook-djoser.urls.py in Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('djoser.urls')
```

- 

```
# pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --name "royalback"  "C:/Users/Shudf/royalback/manage.py"
```

And I can't make it work.

Would anyone be available to help?

Thanks

> raise ImproperlyConfigured(
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
> REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured. You must either
> define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
> settings.configure() before accessing settings. collect_submodules:
> failed to import 'djoser.urls'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with library auto-py-to-exe

Comment: can you please add more details? I get the same error. What did you add in the auto-py-to-exe, thank you in advance